# Logging with fabric and python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, fabric, pytest

How do you use the Python `logging` module with Fabric?

I've set up some tests in my `fabfile.py` and configured the logger, etc, but because it's using `local()` to execute, i guess the logging never gets set up in the tests or function module calls.

Here's an example of my `fabfile.py`:

```
from fabric.api import local
import logging
import module
def unittest(name='all'):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    fh = logging.FileHandler('logs/unittest.log')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - ' +
                                  '%(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.info('Unittest started.')
    local('py.test module')
```

And then in my module, `module.py`

```
import pytest
import logging
def test_main():
    logger = getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('Function started.')
```

The log is filled with the message from `fabfile.py` but nothing from `module.py`

Answer (score 2):

Your module.py has an error on this line:

```
logger = getLogger(__name__)
```

It should be:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

After all you're right: the logger in module.py is independent from the one in the fabfile. If you set up your logger for your test case inside the pytest session then you will be OK.